# How do I print center aligned string in C

Tags: c, printf, centering, stdio

Can anyone help me in printing the `string` aligned to center in C?

For example:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    char x[10] = "Hello";
    char y[10] = "Hello";
    printf ("%*s\n",a, x );
    printf ("%-*s\n",a,y);
}
```

In the above the first prints `Hello` aligned to the right and the second `printf` to the left like this

```
                    Hello
Hello
```

restricting the length for each to 20.

Is there a way to print Hello aligned to the center.

```
        Hello
```

restricting the total length to 20.

Thankyou in advance

Comment: You forgot the little `s` in second `printf` format specifier.

Comment: Thank You 0xF1 for the suggested edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you probably want to avoid centre-aligned text, especially on a console, but in any case; this will take some doing.

The (likely) reason that printf doesn't know how to do this to begin with is that it's not an entirely deterministic operation; not all strings can be centred in all spaces.

Notably, unless `space_for_string - strlen(string)` is an even number, you're going to have to make a choice regarding where you want the string to be shifted to.

In any case, you do want to use the `"%*s"`specifier, but the number you feed into the width field can't be as simple as a flat `20`.

Instead you want to feed it *half the width of your space plus half the width of your string*.

```
int main()
{
  int space = 20;
  char *string = "Hello";
  printf ("%*s\n", space / 2 + strlen(string) / 2,string);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Williham Totland

Answer (score 3):

There is no standardised way to do this with the C `stdio` library. You would have to write your own code to do it with `*printf` calls or with your own `printf` format specifier.

This is a fast and dirty way to do it:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    char x[] = "Hello";

    int length = strlen(x);

    printf ("%*s%*c"
            ,((a - length) >> 1) + length // string length + padding spaces
            , x
            , ((a - length) >> 1) + ((a - length) & 1) // tailing spaces
            , ' '
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ncurses`](http://math.hws.edu/orr/s04/cpsc225/curses.html) library to get to center of a line in terminal and printing your text if you are working on linux.

Comment: +1 for kill flies with a bazooka :P

Comment: @AlterMann: More like a tactical thermonuclear device.

Answer (score 1):

You could, as Williham Totland's answer shows just calculate the required spaces, and use `printf`. Since I'm in the process of refreshing my knowledge (limited though it is), on memory management, I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 20;
    char x[10] = "Hello";
    char *spaces_ptr;//padding str pointer
    a = (a-strlen(x))/2;
    //allocate the required mem, calloc ensures zero terminated
    spaces_ptr = calloc(a + 1, sizeof(char));
    memset(spaces_ptr, ' ', a);//set a chars to hold spaces
    //print
    printf("%s%s", spaces, x);
    free(spaces);//free memory
    return 0;
}
```

Using `sprintf` or `strncat` is an option, too, of course... or even:

```
char *fullStr = calloc(strlen(x) + a + 1, sizeof(char));
memset(fullStr, ' ', a);
strncpy(fullStr+a, x, strlen(x));
puts(fullStr);
free(fullStr);
```

Note that this last snippet is an afterthought, as is the entire answer, really... anyway [check this codepad to see it in action](http://codepad.org/vWACvjLo)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my tiny library: [libTprint](https://github.com/wizzard/libtprint), the code is very simple and you should be able to understand how does it align texts.

Hope it helps you !