# Asterisk Histogram for random dice rolls of 3 dice

Tags: c, random, histogram, dice

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int i;
int d1, d2, d3;
int a[16];
    srand(time(NULL));

for(i = 0; i <= 15; i++)   
    a[i] = 0;   
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 1)   
{   
    d1 = rand() % 6 + 1;   
    d2 = rand() % 6 + 1; 
    d3 = rand() % 6 + 1;  
    ++a[d1 + d2 + d3 - 3];   
}  
char asterisks[0x400];
memset(asterisks, '*', sizeof(asterisks)); 
for(i = 0; i <= 15; i = i + 1) 
{   
    printf("%3d - ", i+3);   

    for(j=0;j<a[i];j++)
    {
    printf("%c ",'*');   

    }
    printf("\n");  
}

return 0;
}
```

Updated code.
The goal is to have an asterisk histogram judging the dice rolls of 3 dice rolled 1000 times. It is to count how many combinations of sums between 3 and 18. 
Histogram output should look like this:

```
Frequency of Results for 3d6
  3 - *
  4 - **
  5 - ****
  6 - *******
  7 - *********
  8 - ***********
  9 - ************
 10 - ************
 11 - *************
 12 - **********
 13 - *************
 14 - ********
 15 - ******
 16 - ***
 17 - ***
 18 - **
```

This is my output as of now:

```
3 - * * 
4 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
5 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
6 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * 
7 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * *     * * * * * * * * * * * * 
8 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
9 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
10 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
11 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * 
12 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
13 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * 
14 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
15 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ** * * * * * * * 
16 - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
17 - * * * * * * * * * 
18 - * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: If a is defined as a 13 entries array, how can you access up to a[18]? And I'm counting only 2 dices..

Comment: @Leeor: stack-overflow... buffer-overflow... the code posted does seem to match the site's name quite well :p

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I apologize, I am trying to learn as we go here...

Comment: @user2306249: No worries... I've tried to answer your question, pointing out a few issues you should address, I hope it helps you on your way

Comment: @user2306249: Instead of writing `++a[d1 + d2 + d3 - 3]`, why not remove the `+1` from all those `d1 = rand() % 6 + 1; ` lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3-18`  You need array with the size of 16

```
int a[16]; 

a[0] indicates Number of 3 counts and 
a[1] indicates Number of 4 counts and 
....

a[15] indicates Number of 18 counts.
```

You need to change this for loop

```
 for(i = 0; i <= 15; i++)   
  a[i] = 0;
```

and this statement

```
   a[d1 + d2+d3] = a[d1 + d2 + d3] + 1;
```

Modify like this

```
     ++a[d1 + d2 + d3 - 3];
```

And final for loop also, you need two loops.

```
for(i = 0; i <= 15; i = i + 1) 
   {   
    printf("%3d - ", i+3);   

    for(j=0;j<a[i];j++)
       {
        printf("%c ",'*');   

       }
        printf("\n");  
   }
```

Comment: where does the j come from?

Comment: @user2306249 You need to declare additional variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memset` to fill a buffer with asterisks and `"%*s"` `printf` format to print as many as you need:

```
char asterisks[0x400];
memset(asterisks, '*', sizeof(asterisks));

for(i = 3; i <= 18; i = i + 1)   
{   
    printf("%d - %*s\n", i, a[i], asterisks);  
}
```

And yeah as mentioned in the comments you should define `a` long enough:

```
int a[19];
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to fill a char array with asterisks can be done in various ways, a few of which have been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492858/how-do-i-print-center-aligned-string-in-c), a question that was posted but a few hours ago...

On a different matter:
You're calling the `rand` function, without providing a seed... `rand` will then, by default, behave as though it was passed `1` as a seed, and your compiled program will produce *not-so-random* results.
Consider adding this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
int d1, d2;
int a[13];
    srand(time(NULL));//seed current time
}
```

That, and, as Jongware pointed out:

```
d1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
d2 = rand() %6 + 1;
```

just doesn't make sense:

```
d1 = rand() % 18 + 1;
```

Does just the same thing, requiring only 1 function call. But still, there is another issue with what you're doing with this int value:

You're also using an array of ints (`a[13]`), the declaration of which implies that the highest offset you can use is 12, the lowest (as ever) is 0. Yet, your loops start at offset 3, and go all the way up to 18... 
I know this site is called stackoverflow, but your code seems to be *actively working towards [Buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)*. Fix that, please...

Comment: A less obvious optimization: call `rand` once, for a range of 3..18.

Comment: @Jongware: You're right (I've added that to my answer, crediting you), but the OP has bigger fish to fry IMO... not in the least: the overflow problem

Comment: Um, my suggestion was to start at **3** -- you can at least throw three ones :-) (As commented elsethread, a range of "0..15" works *exactly* the same.)